# Macro to fill bookmark and saves few PDF files

Tags: excel, vba, bookmarks

I'm currently stuck within the development of a macro to transfer data from an Excel Sheet to a word template with bookmark.
For now, the main of the macro is working, the data are well transfered to the Template but I have several issues that I cannot fix since yesterday, and I tried a lot since.
1/ When I want to save the document in PDF, my macro will keep the information paste in the template after closing the docx, therefore, the next pdf file will have the information of two line instead of one. I tried to use an export function but I had the same result. Do you have any idea of how I could change my code to let the template empty after registered to pdf file ?

2/ To name the PDF file, I defined different variable but it seems to not work, indeed, it seems that the name is defined with the information of the N-1 cells instead of the information from the N cell, any idea to solve it ? Also, I cannot figure out how to put the YEAR information in the name of the file ( I have a compatibility error, I think it's because of the data format )

3/ To end, I want to set up a IF & Then to take into account only the line concerning the current year, I didn't find how to make it work efficiently, could you give me some suggestion ?

You can find my VBA code here :

```
' Macro1 Macro
'
Option Explicit

'Filepath to the data and template
Const FilePath As String = "C:\Users\\OneDrive\Desktop\fiches\Templates\" & "Template macro.docx"""
Dim wd As New Word.Application
Dim NomCell As Range

Sub CreateWordDocuments()
'Defini a counter
Dim i As Integer
Dim prenom As String
Dim nom As String
Dim interviewyear As Date
i = 0
'create copy of Word in memory
Dim doc As Word.Document
wd.Visible = True
Dim NomRange As Range

'create a reference to all the people
Range("A2").Select
Set NomRange = Range(ActiveCell, ActiveCell.End(xlDown))
'for each person in list
For Each NomCell In NomRange

'open a document in Word

Set doc = wd.Documents.Open("C:\Users\\OneDrive\Desktop\fiches\Templates\" & "Template macro.docx")

'go to each bookmark and type in details
'If Year(Cells(NomCell, 14)) >= Year(Date) Then

CopyCell "Age", 4
CopyCell "Ancienneté", 6
CopyCell "Projet", 9
CopyCell "Grade", 10
CopyCell "Rôle", 11
CopyCell "Date_de_départ_prévue", 12
CopyCell "Carrière_manager", 13
CopyCell "Motif_départ", 16
CopyCell "Motif_départ_2", 17
CopyCell "Points_positifs_expérience", 18
CopyCell "Point_négatifs_expérience", 19
CopyCell "Situation_future_entreprise_ou_autre", 20
CopyCell "Commentaire_RRH", 21
CopyCell "Prénom", 2
CopyCell "Site", 7
CopyCell "Service_line", 8
CopyCell "Nom", 1
CopyCell "Date_entretien_de_départ", 15
CopyCell "RRH_entretien", 16


prenom = Cells(NomCell, 2).Value
nom = Cells(NomCell, 3).Value
'interviewyear = Cells(NomCell, 15).Date


'save and close this document
doc.SaveAs2 FilePath & nom & " " & prenom & interviewyear & ".pdf", wdExportFormatPDF
doc.Close
i = i + 1

Next NomCell
wd.Quit

MsgBox "The work is done, " & i & "  files had been created in " & FilePath & "!"

'End If
End Sub


Sub CopyCell(BookMarkNom As String, ColumnOffset As Integer)

'copy each cell to relevant Word bookmark
wd.Selection.Goto What:=wdGoToBookmark, Name:=BookMarkNom
wd.Selection.TypeText NomCell.Offset(0, ColumnOffset).Value

   
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Untested, but you can try something like this.  Relying on ActiveCell/Selection etc is not very robust, so you'd be better off avoiding that type of approach.

```vb
'Filepath to the data and template
Const FilesPath As String = "C:\Users\username\OneDrive\Desktop\fiches\"
Const TemplatesPath As String = FilesPath & "Templates\"
Const TemplateFile As String = "Template macro.docx"

Sub CreateWordDocuments()
    Dim i As Long
    Dim prenom As String
    Dim nom As String
    Dim interviewyear
    Dim wd As Word.Application
    Dim doc As Word.Document
    Dim NomRange As Range, NomCell As Range, ws As Worksheet

    i = 0

    Set ws = ActiveSheet 'for example
    Set NomRange = ws.Range("A2", ws.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp))
    
    Set wd = New Word.Application 'open Word
    wd.Visible = True

    For Each NomCell In NomRange.Cells
        
        Set doc = wd.Documents.Open(TemplatesPath & TemplateFile)
        With NomCell.EntireRow
            interviewyear = Year(.Cells(15).Value) 'year from date
            If interviewyear = Year(Date) Then 'from this year?
                'this is easier than calling a separate sub I think...
                doc.Bookmarks("Age").Range.Text = .Cells(5).Value 'or .Columns("E").Value
                doc.Bookmarks("Ancienneté").Range.Text = .Cells(7).Value
                doc.Bookmarks("Projet").Range.Text = .Cells(10).Value
                doc.Bookmarks("Grade").Range.Text = .Cells(11).Value
                'etc etc
                
                prenom = .Cells(2).Value
                nom = .Cells(3).Value
                doc.SaveAs2 FilesPath & nom & " " & prenom & interviewyear & ".pdf", wdExportFormatPDF
                doc.Close False
                i = i + 1
            End If 'current year
        End With
    Next NomCell
    wd.Quit
    MsgBox "The work is done, " & i & "  files had been created in " & FilesPath & "!"
End Sub
```